# Unable to resize img in div using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, tumblr, image-size, tumblr-themes

I'm a beginner programmer and I am creating a tumblr theme but I've come across a problem. I have two sidebars (left and right) that I've added the same background img to, but I am unable to resize the img to the proportions of the div.

It took me some time to get the image in the right location, but now it's too big. I've tried multiple avenues to resize it, but nothing changed. My intentions are to make the image customizable, so regardless of the image, it'll fit the div. If anyone has any suggestions, I'm all ears.

I've tried max-width/max-height, background-position and background-size, etc.

```css
.leftbar {
    width:246px;
    height:775px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:60px;
    border-radius:100px;}

#sidebarborder {
    width:185px;
    height:725px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:17px;
    margin-left:22px;
    border:8px solid {color:border background};
    border-radius:90px;}

#sidebarimg {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;}
```

```html
<meta name="image:sidebar background" content=""/>
<div id="sidebarimg">
    <img src="{image:sidebar background}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post all the relevant HTML instead of commenting roughly how it's structured? 

One thing I see is that you aren't targeting the image element with CSS so it is free to be as big as it wants. I would add the `sidebarimg` ID to the image element or target the image element with those CSS rules.

Comment: If the same image is being used in two opposite sidebars, use a class (`.sidebarimg`) instead of an id (`#sidebarimg`). Then put `<div class="sidebarimg">`. Try setting a background-size attribute to your CSS: `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;`. ('Cover' will crop the image to fit if necessary)

Comment: p.s. instead of placing an image tag inside the div, background-size would require adding the image as a background to the CSS: `background-image: url("image.gif");`

Comment: @adr5240 That worked! Thank you so so much!